# Add properties to modern site programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sitepages, office-dev-pnp, modern-team-site

I want to add some metadata to my modern Team Site.

I can achieve this by simply adding columns to the Site Pages library in the site contents.

Now I want to do the same thing programmatically using CSOM.

I use the following code for that purpose:

```
var pages = siteContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");
var fieldCreationInformation = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.Entities.FieldCreationInformation(fieldType)
{
    DisplayName = fieldName,
    InternalName = fieldName.Replace(" ", ""),
    AddToDefaultView = true,
    Required = false,
    Id = Guid.NewGuid()
};
pages.CreateField(fieldCreationInformation);
```

This works - the fields are getting added to the pages library, however they don't appear as the properties when I'm editing the page, unlike the columns added in the GUI.

Why? How can I add columns programmatically and see them as page properties?

Comment: Would you be open to using PowerShell PnP instead of CSOM?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov Well, yeah. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Added an answer with a PowerShell PnP used instead of CSOM. PowerShell PnP uses CSOM behind-the-scenes, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tasks like these, I highly recommend using [PowerShell PnP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps). It's a fantastic, powerful and easy-to use PowerShell Module.

This is what you want to do in only 4 lines including Installation of the module:

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity "Site Pages"
Add-PnPField -List $list -Type Text -InternalName "Age" -DisplayName "Age"
```

If you use **PowerShell ISE** or Visual Studio code - you get intellisense with autocomplete like so:

[image]

This is the result:
[image]

**Update: Adding field to the content type**

You can also try adding existing field to the content type you need:

```
Add-PnPFieldToContentType -Field "Age" -ContentType " Wiki Page"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this works in just about the same way as my CSOM code, which means that the field is added to the Site Pages library but it doesn't appear in page Properties in the Page details as you showed in the screenshot. I'm still getting information `There are no custom properties available to add. Site owners can create properties by adding columns in the Pages library.` in the Properties section. What could I possibly have done wrong?

Comment: I think I have a good idea what is wrong. Most likely you have several content types. Can you modify the View and display Content type so that you can see existing page's content types? Also, when you click on "new" - what are the options there? What are the available content types?

Comment: I see. I have the following content types: Wiki Page, Web Part Page, Site Page, Repost Page and the Wiki Page is set as default. When I check Add to all content types option when creating a new column from gui I get the desired result, otherwise I won't see the column as a property.

Comment: So the solution here is to add the field not to the list, but to the desired content type directly.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the CSOM C# code to achieve it.

```
string siteUrl="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";
string userName = "lz@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "xxx";

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
List oList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");

var schemaField = "<Field DisplayName='MyField' Type='Text' />";
Field oField = oList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(schemaField, true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue | AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

**More information**:[Creating fields using CSOM](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/creating-fields-using-csom/)